# Using 'navigation' in 'cardview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen with card views.

Each card view has:

- 1x picture
- 1x title
- 1x description
- 1x touchable opacity

I was hoping to figure out a way that each touchable opacity has different navigation.
Item 0 will have navigation to screen x, the item 1 will have navigation to screen y.

My doubt is it possible to have different functions for each touchable opacity ?

```
function ServiceCoverageButtong() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('GeneralInformationSupportScreen')}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Teste</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const CardItemNewsProvider = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} key={index}>
      <Image source={item.imgUrl} style={styles.image} />
      <Text style={styles.header}>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.body}>{item.body}</Text>
      <ServiceCoverageButtong />
    </View>
  );
};
```

How can I create several functions and use the `item` of `CardItemNewsProvider`?

I am new to React Native and I am struggling with doing that.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can pass a prop to your `<ServiceCoverageButtong state={"0"}/>`

And in your ServiceCoverageButtong() get the state from your props and run a check on what should be returned.

```
    function ServiceCoverageButtong({state}) {
      const navigation = useNavigation();

if (state == "0") {
      return (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('GeneralInformationSupportScreen')}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Teste</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
} else {
return (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('anotherScreen')}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Teste</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use one component for your buttons, you can just add `onPress` prop to your `DataNewsProvider`

```
let DataNewsProvider = [
    {
      title: NewsHomeCountryTitle,
      body: NewsHomeCountryBody,
      imgUrl: Images.newsYourCountryImage,
      textButton: NewsTextButton,
      onPress: () => navigation.navigate('GeneralInformationSupportScreen'),
    },
    {
      title: NewsWorldwideTitle,
      body: NewsWorldwideBody,
      imgUrl: Images.newsWorldwideImage,
      textButton: NewsTextButton,
      onPress: () => navigation.navigate('anotherScreen'),
    },
  ];
```

And pass it to your button components TouchableOpacity

```
const CardItemNewsProvider = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} key={index}>
      <Image source={item.imgUrl} style={styles.image} />
      <Text style={styles.header}>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.body}>{item.body}</Text>
      <ServiceCoverageButtong state={item.stateButton} onPress={item.onPress}/>
    </View>
  );
};
```

This way you don't need to have additional conditions, and you just pass those functions as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks caslawter!

For anyone interested.

```
function ServiceCoverageButtong({state}) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  if (state === '0') {
    console.log('state', state);
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('GeneralInformationSupportScreen')
          }>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Hi I'm a test</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    console.log('state', state);
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('anotherScreen')}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>You're really into testing</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const CardItemNewsProvider = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} key={index}>
      <Image source={item.imgUrl} style={styles.image} />
      <Text style={styles.header}>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.body}>{item.body}</Text>
      <ServiceCoverageButtong state={item.stateButton} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

And another snipet:

```
  let DataNewsProvider = [
    {
      title: NewsHomeCountryTitle,
      body: NewsHomeCountryBody,
      imgUrl: Images.newsYourCountryImage,
      textButton: NewsTextButton,
      stateButton: '0',
    },
    {
      title: NewsWorldwideTitle,
      body: NewsWorldwideBody,
      imgUrl: Images.newsWorldwideImage,
      textButton: NewsTextButton,
      stateButton: '1',
    },
  ];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).